# What is an Android Kernal and how does it differ from the Android Version?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand the difference between the Kernal for Android and the Android version.

I read [this](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-z-what-kernel) guide explaining what a Kernal is and what the Kernal is for Android (answer: special Linux kernel), but I don't understand how this differs from the Android Version. I know they are two different things. The Android Kernal and the Android Version are NOT the same thing.

Does this mean that the Android Kernal has it's own version separate from the Android Version which updates totally separately? So for example, your Android phone might prompt you to update it's Android version, but would your Android phone ever prompt you to update it's Kernal?

Can you have the same Android Version but run it on two different Kernals? Really confused here...

Comment: if you want to think of cars, "android version" is "This is the 2005-2007 model year of Car X". kernel version "this is the 2006 model, using the 2005-2007 styling". within an android version (e.g. 4.0, 4.4, 5.0) the major interfaces should remain consistent, while the kernel version can change in response to bug fix releases. a new android version demands a new kernel version, while a new kernel version doesn't necessarily  mean a new android version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> your Android phone might prompt you to update it's Android version

More accurately, your Android device might prompt you to install a firmware update. This would replace the existing firmware with an updated edition of Android, including its kernel.

> would your Android phone ever prompt you to update it's Kernal?

Only in the context of prompting you to install a firmware update.

> Can you have the same Android Version but run it on two different Kernals?

Yes, you can have the same Android OS version running on different kernels. Some manufacturers will ship different kernel builds than you might find other manufacturers use, for whatever reason (e.g., addressing certain bugs that their specific devices encounter in the kernel).